# HTML ignores German letters in paragraph

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have a paragraph line:

```
<p>anbei erhalten Sie ihren Neustartalert für die Suche <strong>{{$u->search}}</strong></p>
```

but on the website it is written `anbei erhalten Sie ihren Neustartalert fr die Suche` für without ü. But this strong value `$u->searach` is TüV and it shows properly.

So it is like this:

```
anbei erhalten Sie ihren Neustartalert fr die Suche TüV
```

Why is it like so? I've included `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>`inside head tag but didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ü -> &uuml;
```

You should use the HTML-tag which displays the correct special character in UTF-8.

Comment: Nice! It works, but why doesn't it work with UTF-8 in meta?

Comment: Since you've been using HTML4+ u need a reference between the old character and the HTML4-character like seen above.
http://www.utf8-chartable.de/